# Angular2: issues converting a form's value to a Model with default fields

Tags: rest, angular

I am busy with a Stock take form that needs to be posted to a REST API.  I have a stockTake model which has three fields that get initialized with default values of 0.  the three fields "StockTakeID, IDKey and PackSize" are not part of the angular form where the data needs to be entered.  My issue is submitting the model with those three fields with default values to my RestService.  When I submit the stockTakeForm.value I get an error as those three fields are not part of the data that's being submitted...  Any idea how I can go about getting this to work?

my stock-take.model.ts:

```
export class StockTakeModel {

    constructor(
    StockTakeID: number = 0,
        IDKey: number = 0,
        BarCode: number,
        ProductCode: string,
        SheetNo: string,
        BinNo: string,
        Quantity: number,
        PackSize: number = 0) { }
}
```

my stock-take.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';

import { StockTakeModel } from '../../models/stock-take.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'stock-take',
  templateUrl: './stock-take.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock-take.component.css']
})
export class StockTakeComponent implements OnInit {
    stockTakeForm: FormGroup;   

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private restService: RestService) { 
    this.stockTakeForm = fb.group({
        'sheetNo':['', Validators.required],
        'binNo':['', Validators.required],
        'barcode':['', Validators.required],
        'Qty':['', Validators.required]
    }); 
    }

  submitStockTake(stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel) {
      //console.log(stockTakeModel);

    this.restService.postStockTake(stockTakeModel)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    },
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure: " + res);
    }
    );
    this.stockTakeForm.reset();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

my stock-take.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
        <h1>Stock Take</h1>
        <br /><br />
        <form [formGroup]="stockTakeForm" role="form" (ngSubmit)="submitStockTake(stockTakeForm.value)">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Sheet Number" class="form-control" id="sheetNo" [formControl]="stockTakeForm.controls['sheetNo']" name="sheetNo">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Bin Number" class="form-control" id="binNo" [formControl]="stockTakeForm.controls['binNo']" name="binNo">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Barcode" class="form-control" id="bCode" [formControl]="stockTakeForm.controls['barcode']" name="barcode">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Quantity" clas="form-control" id="Qty" [formControl]="stockTakeForm.controls['Qty']" name="quantity">
            <button class="btn btn-block" [disabled]="!stockTakeForm.valid">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

updated stock-take.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';

import { StockTakeModel } from '../../models/stock-take.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'stock-take',
  templateUrl: './stock-take.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock-take.component.css']
})
export class StockTakeComponent implements OnInit {
    stockTakeForm: FormGroup;
    stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private restService: RestService) { 
    this.stockTakeForm = fb.group({
        'sheetNo':['', Validators.required],
        'binNo':['', Validators.required],
        'barcode':['', Validators.required],
        'Qty':['', Validators.required]
    });
    }

    doStockTake(val: any) {
        //console.log("val:" + JSON.stringify(val));
        this.stockTakeModel = new StockTakeModel(0, 0, val[Object.keys(val)[2]], '', val[Object.keys(val)[0]], val[Object.keys(val)[1]], val[Object.keys(val)[3]], 0);

//  console.log(this.stockTakeModel);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.stockTakeModel));
    }

  submitStockTake(stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel) {
      //console.log(stockTakeModel);

    this.restService.postStockTake(stockTakeModel)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    },
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure: " + res);
    }
    );
    this.stockTakeForm.reset();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would to create a new variable, e.g: 
`stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel;`

if that doesn't work (as you said it complained about undefined), you can also instantiate it as an empty Object, like so:

`stockTakeModel = {};`

EDIT, so you changed your code to something like this: I also added some console.logs to show where it is undefined, as there was a little question about that.

```
stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel; // undefined at this point (or empty if you have defined it as empty above)!

// use Object keys to access the keys in the val object, a bit messy, but will work!
submitStockTake(val: any) {
  this.stockTakeModel = 
    new StockTakeModel(0, 0, val[Object.keys(val)[2]], '', val[Object.keys(val)[0]], 
       val[Object.keys(val)[1]], val[Object.keys(val)[3]]);  

  // console.log(this.StockTakeModel); // now it should have all values!

  this.restService.postStockTake(this.stockTakeModel)
     .subscribe(d => { console.log(d)} ) // just shortened your code a bit 
  this.stockTakeForm.reset();
  }
```

EDIT: So finally the last issue is solved, besides the solution above. It's because your `StockTakeModel`-class wasn't properly declared the value was undefined, or actually empty. So fix your class to:

```
export class StockTakeModel {

    constructor(
    public StockTakeID: number = 0, // you were missin 'public' on everyone
        public IDKey: number = 0,
        public BarCode: number,
        public ProductCode: string,
        public SheetNo: string,
        public BinNo: string,
        public Quantity: number,
        public PackSize: number = 0) { }
}
```

Note also that in your 'updated' code you still have `(ngSubmit)="submitStockTake(stockTakeForm.value)` in your form, so your created `doStockTake`-method is not called.

Comment: I added the following function:  doStockTake(val: any) { this.stockTakeModel = new StockTakeModel(0, 0, val.barcode, '', val.sheetNo, val.binNo, val.Qty, 0); } I changed the ngSubmit to use the doStockTake function.  After I instantiate the stockTakeModel when I console.log it it's undefined...  Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Any when I try it the way you suggested I get an error saying e.g. property StockTakeID does not exist on stockTakeModel...  i'm guessing as it's still undefined at that stage?

Comment: Okay, your method looks correct. So where and how do you instantiate it, and where do you try to console.log it? :)

Comment: I instantiate it in my stock-take.component.ts...  stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel;
I console.log it in the doStockTake() method above...  something strange is going wrong...

Comment: Well, when you instantiate it like `stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel` it's at that point undefined, as you have just typed it to being a StockTakeModel, but not given it any values.

Comment: But in the doStockTakeModel I then do stockTakeMOdel = new StockTakeModel(...);  and for some reason it's still undefined after that...

Comment: Thanks for all your time/persistence...  It's still giving me a undefined...  I added my updated code at the bottom of my question...  Maybe I should try a template driven form rather?

Comment: Found it :D Copied your code in a local project, and finally found the problem, why it creates empty object. Your class wasn't properly formed. Now I know for a fact that it works, I have tested it myself :D So check the updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!  You've helped me so much over the past 2 weeks, hope I can return the favour sometime:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the construction [formControl] in your template.
There should be at least [ngModel].

Usualy I use, for two-way communication, the [(ngModel)]. Not the [formControl].

So your template code should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
        <h1>Stock Take</h1>
        <br /><br />
        <form [formGroup]="stockTakeForm" role="form" (ngSubmit)="submitStockTake(stockTakeForm.value)">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Sheet Number" class="form-control" id="sheetNo" [(ngModel)]="stockTakeForm.controls['sheetNo']" name="sheetNo">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Bin Number" class="form-control" id="binNo" [(ngModel)]="stockTakeForm.controls['binNo']" name="binNo">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Barcode" class="form-control" id="bCode" [(ngModel)]="stockTakeForm.controls['barcode']" name="barcode">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Quantity" clas="form-control" id="Qty" [(ngModel)]="stockTakeForm.controls['Qty']" name="quantity">
            <button class="btn btn-block" [disabled]="!stockTakeForm.valid">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding my question:  I have no issues getting the values from the form as it's a model driven form that as far as I know doesn't need ngModel.  The question is getting those values into a StockTake model which has three default values in it's constructor

Comment: Ok, sorry. About default values - I'd manually made the assignments into the constructor and submit with the JSONified values. It looks like you should go this way. If you want to submit data that's not in the form-control scope, it's the only way. Maybe I'm wrong, but... you can always be sure only for the code written by yourself ;)